# Cheap solution to shoot during several hours at night?

Tags: video

I'm facing an annoying problem, for the last few weeks somebody in my neighborhood steals gas from my motorcycle.
It's a Honda VT125 Shadow, all the wires and hoses under the tank are apparent. So the guy unplugs the hoses and siphons the tank.

So i'm looking for a way to film the bike at night to try and find out who this jacka** is.

The street isn't very dark at night.

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) would be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your best bet is to look through the surveillance section on amazon and see what your options are for your budget...100 bucks seems to get you a pretty good setup.

http://www.amazon.com/Security-Surveillance-Home-Automation/b?ie=UTF8&node=524136

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a camcorder?  If you do you can probably connect it to a PC or Mac with firewire and use capture software to record to a HDD with overnight.

If you have the hardware already it's just a matter of finding software (iMovie for Mac is an option, as well as Premier for windows), and making sure you have a HDD large enough for several hours of video.

Another option would be to stay out one night waiting for him.  If it's just a thug maybe all he needs is a good scare - maybe you could yell or shine a bright flashlight at him.

Comment: Sorry, I would've voted you up if not for the "handgun or shotgun" part. I would suggest you edit that out as it has nothing to do with AVP and condones violence.

Comment: @BartArondson ok.